# How to put the first line of text file in the end position

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I am using visual studio 2012 C#. I have a stream writer. I wrote into a text file all lines but I want to put the first line in the last position of the text file. After writing the stream, i want to switch first line to the last but the first line should not be left blank but to shift the preceding lines up and then write the stream again. How can i Hold the first line in a variable and start writing from second line and in which part of the code.

Here is my code

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath))  
           {  
               string[] buffer = new string[count];  

               while (!(lines = reader.ReadLine()).Contains("Records"))  
               {  



                   for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)  
                   {        
                       string[] fields = lines.Split('|');  


                       Result[i, 0] = "";  

                           Result[i, 1] = fields[1];                                 
                           Result[i, 2] = " ";  

                           Result[i, 3] = xx;  

                           Result[i, 4] = "";  
                           Result[i, 5] = fields[4];  
                           Result[i, 6] = "";  
                           Result[i, 7] = fields[0];                                
                           Result[i, 8] = "";  

                           if (fields[15].Contains("PASS"))  
                           {  
                               Result[i, 9] = "P";  
                           }  
                           else if (fields[15].Contains("FAIL"))  
                           {  
                               Result[i, 9] = "F";  
                           }                                                          
                           Result[i, 10] = "";  
                           Result[i, 11] = "";                                                   
                           Result[i, 12] = "";  
                           Result[i, 13] = "";  
                           Result[i, 14] = "";  

                           }  

                       }  



                       else if (fields.Length == 7)  
                       {  


                           Result[i, 1] = "";  

                           Result[i, 2] = "";  


                           Result[i, 3] = fields[0];                                                       //Test Code  
                           Result[i, 4] = "1";                                                                 // Test Channel  
                           Result[i, 5] =fields [4];                                                           // Test Value  
                           Result[i, 6] = "0";                                                             //Test Frequency  

                           if (fields[5].Contains("PASS"))   
                           {   
                               Result[i, 7] = "P";   
                           }  
                           else if (fields[5].Contains("FAIL"))   
                           {  
                               Result[i, 7] = "F";   
                           }   



                           Result[i, 8] = "0";                             // Test Volt



                                   Result[i, 9] = fields[1];  

                                   Result[i, 10] = "0.0";  

                               }  


                           }  

                           Result[i, 11] = "0";                       
                           Result[i, 12] = "1";                       
                           Result[i, 13] = "1";                      
                           Result[i, 14] = "0";                   
                           Result[i, 15] = Profile_Index.ToString();  

                       }        
                       result = ("PATS_TEST" + "," + Result[i, 1] + "," + Result[i, 2] + "," + Result[i, 3] + "," + Result[i, 4] + "," + Result[i, 5] + "," + Result[i, 6] + "," + Result[i, 7] + "," + Result[i, 8] + "," + Result[i, 9] + "," + Result[i, 10] + "," + Result[i, 11] + "," + Result[i, 12] + "," + Result[i, 13] + "," + Result[i, 14] + "," + Result[i, 15]);                                                                  
                       if (fields[0].Contains("END-OF-LINE"))  
                       {  
                           result = ("END-OF-LINE");  
                       }              
                   }             
                   Profile_Index++;             
                   // Console.WriteLine(result);        
                   file.WriteLine(result);                                                        
                       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by this code.just see this.

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line = null;
            string FirstLineContent = "";
            int line_number = 0;
            int line_to_delete = 1;
            string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Sample.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line_number++;
                        if (line_number == line_to_delete)
                        {
                            FirstLineContent = line;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(FirstLineContent);
                }
            }
            File.Delete(@"D:\Sample.txt");
            File.Move(tempFile, @"D:\Sample.txt");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer looks good. But I've tried to make it shorter and with fewer variables.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //first we read all lines into a list
    List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Sample.txt"))
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine());

    //if there are more than 1 lines...
    if (allLines.Count > 1)
    {
        //copy first line to end
        allLines.Add(allLines.First());
        //remove first line
        allLines.RemoveAt(0);
        //finally we write everything back in the same file
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Sample.txt"))
            foreach (var line in allLines)
                writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

- First we read all the lines in a list.
- We copy the first line to the end of the list.
- We remove the first line.
- Finally we write everything back in the same file.

Comment: Its also can be a answer. Thanks for your response.